# How to create chart view for list data

Tags: sharepoint-online, view, chart-web-part

In Business Data Category, chart web part is not available.How to create chart view for the existing list

Answer (score 3):

It seems that ChartWebPart & ChartViewWebPart are not populated in webpart gallery. Follow below steps

1. Go to site setting. (Site collection)
2. Click on `Web parts` under `Web Designer Galleries`.
3. On Files tab in ribbon, Click on `New Document`.
4. Find '`ChartWebPart`' and '`ChartViewWebPart`' and select their check-boxes.
5. Go up and click on '`Populate Gallery`' button.

Now ChartWebPart & ChartViewWebPart will available under `miscellaneous` category.

Answer (score 1):

You should enable the `"SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features"` at the site collection level.

You can find the `"Site collection feature"` management link on the

- Site Actions >
- Site Settings page under the section `"Site Collection Administration"`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Gantt-chart type view available as part of the 'Tasks' app. 
You would therefore need to create a new list in that app.

- Go to your Site contents.
- 'Add an app', select 'Tasks'. Develop your app content.
- Then when you go to the page you want to have a chart view on, you will find your tasks app under 'Insert / Web part / Apps'.